# Difficulties in understanding natural join

Tags: sql, database, natural-join

I'm having problems understanding the main point of natural join in database systems. According to the definition, the natural join selects the combination of 2 tables having the same values of columns whose names equal.

My problem is: what if there are two different values of the same named columns? They will be dropped, but what if I need some information from that dropped tuples?

Can someone please explain this to me using examples?

Comment: please answer me before closing my question if you find it too simple!!!!!!

Comment: FYI I think this is a "coding" question - read my answer for why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values don't need to be unique, and you shouldn't have "dropped" tupples.

A natural join is for lazy, trusting and bad programmers:

- lazy: can't be bothered typing in the join conditions
- trusting: hopes that when same-named columns are added to both tables that their queries don't suddenly break
- bad: the essence of good programming is clarity. Using a natural join obscures how the joins are being made, so the reader of your query must check the table definitions to figure out what's going on

IMHO using natural joins is a terrible idea and they should never be used. You gain virtually nothing (you save typing maybe a dozen chars) and lose a *lot*.

#### EDIT:

natural joins are like any other join in terms of inner/outer: the default is inner join, but you can soecify left or right joins too, for example in mysql:

```
select ...
from t1
natural left join t2
```

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, for me it is kind of not intuitiv to understand why one uses natural join

Comment: i am learning for my database final exam, and there a lot of relational algebra questions in handouts. i cannot somtimes follow the task cos there are min. 3 steps in the background until i understand the query

Comment: For completeness, one sort-of benefit of `NATURAL JOIN` is that the columns being compared aren't repeated in the result set. This is only an advantage if you do `SELECT *`, which you generally shouldn't do in the first place, and it's something you can also get with `JOIN USING`.

Comment: @hvd. but what about the values being dropped? what if i need the value which was dropped? if i do natural join, i am losing information unwillingly, right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dropped"? I have no idea what you are talking about. Afaik the result of a natural join is the same as if you coded the join condition manually

Comment: @doniyor If you mean that rows from one table with no matching rows in the other table will be dropped, then you're not losing information unwillingly, you specifically *told* the database to drop that data by performing an inner join.

Comment: @hvd not true. You can have natural outer johns - see edit

Comment: @Bohemian Your edit doesn't contradict my comment, but you're right, and I actually didn't know about that, so thanks. :)